# The same multiple object posting by ajax and jquery to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need help with posting the same objects from view to controller.

MODEL
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Surname {get; set;}

VIEW

```
<input type="text" id="name" /> <input type="text" id="surname" />
<input type="text" id="name" /> <input type="text" id="surname" />
<input type="text" id="name" /> <input type="text" id="surname" />
<input type="text" id="name" /> <input type="text" id="surname" />
```

if i would have only one field with name and surname, it would be easy i think:
var model = { name: $("#name#).val(), surname: $("#surname#).val()}

but the problem is that, I dont know how many fields(models) will be filled and ganerated, because it depends on user, (new couple of fields (name and surname) will be adding dynamic by user)

thanks for helping

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID. It's not valid HTML. You need to find another way to dynamically add the fields to the page without duplicating IDs

Comment: can't repeat ID's in a page and you need a `name` on input to submit. Study how html forms work

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/v44apr1p/

HTML:

```
<div id="input-wrapper">
    <div id="initial-input" class="input-holder">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> 
        <input type="text" id="surname" /> 
    </div>
    <a class="add-another">Add<a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".add-another").on('click', function(){
    var $new = $('#initial-input').clone();
    var count = $(".input-holder").length;
    $new.attr('id', "clone" + count )
    $new.find('input').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('name', 'name' + count).attr('id', 'name' + count);
    });
    $('#input-wrapper').append($new);
});
```